# How to clean tubeless tire sealant from rims

Tags: tire, cleaning, tubeless, sealant

How to clean the stuck/dry sealant from the rim edge, and the rim tape, etc? (In order to replace my old tubeless tyres with new, and the new ones to sit on a clean/fresh surface). With water? Water/soap? Any other liquid?

Answer (score 3):

I did this weekend. It was not hard to do it mechanically with a piece of cloth and water. Then for patching I needed a piece of a very clean surface so I used a dish-washing liquid and then finally isopropanol, but that will probably not be necessary if you do not need patching.

From the rims the mechanical way was enough, a dry piece of cloth or even just fingers were fine, but a wet cloth will be even easier.

Comment: brake cleaner works very well, but i only tried it without rim tape: it could ruin it.

Answer (score 1):

Tubeless tire sealants and generally latex based, so anything that will remove latex.

Adhesive remover is probably the best bet, e.g. Goo-Gone (sold in the US at least, I don't know if that brand is used elsewhere);

Comment: Goo-Gone is pretty high up there on the harshness index.  It does indeed clean up latex paint (I have some myself and even used it 40 years ago when I did a lot of painting), but I would be careful on a carbon wheel with goo gone.  It may be OK, but I would be leery risking it there.  On an aluminum wheel however, go to town with the stuff.  You won't affect the aluminum with goo gone.  Just be careful of rim tape and any rubber parts like where the valve stem enters the rim.  Just in case.